# SQL query for update rows in a table and insert those as new rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This is want to achieve:-

- Get some rows(x) from a table t.
- Change one col value(f) in all those x rows.
- Then insert those x as new rows in the same table t.

This procedure is not working with this error:-

> You can't specify target table 't' for update in FROM clause

This is my procedure

```
DELIMITER //
DROP procedure IF EXISTS copy_values //
CREATE PROCEDURE copy_values(
IN source_id char(36), 
IN dest_id char(36))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO t (a, b, c, d, e, f)
VALUES (
    (SELECT a FROM t WHERE t_cid=source_id), 
    (SELECT b FROM t WHERE t_cid=source_id), 
    (SELECT c FROM t WHERE t_cid=source_id), 
    (SELECT d FROM t WHERE t_cid=source_id), 
    (SELECT e FROM t WHERE t_cid=source_id), 
    dest_id
    );
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Can you suggest an alternative query for solving this use case?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and consider whether you really need a procedure for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `INSERT ... SELECT ...` should work.

```
...
INSERT INTO t
            (a,
             ...
             e,
             f)
            SELECT a,
                   ...
                   e,
                   dest_id
                   FROM t
                   WHERE t_cid = source_id;
...
```

Comment: This query would not solve the use case. In my case dest_id is not present in the table t. It is some constant value like "213" which has to be put in f column for all rows.
(a,b,c,d,e) we are picking from t but value of col f we are hardcoding

Comment: @ShivanshRajolia-HeLleR: Yes, I saw that it is a parameter to the procedure. But you can use constants (in the context of the query) in queries. In the particular case it should be bound to the parameter if there is no column with the same name. Have you even tried it?

Comment: yes I tried that. It does not work. INSERT INTO SELECT statement works if you directly want to transfer some rows from one table to another...cannot handle constants+cannot insert into the same table you are doing select from. 
That is why I tried INSERT INTO VALUES SELECT still getting the error mentioned. I think maybe some other approach for query might be needed here. Maybe insert will not work.

Comment: @ShivanshRajolia-HeLleR: It works perfectly here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=900432306eff274b8e8498de42c25930 Must be something else you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot @stickybit .This fiddle is correct. For some reason same thing is not working in my local system. But this is the correct answer. Marking it as the answer.